# Symfony 3 application running on OSX

Tags: symfony, docker

My Symfony 3.4 application is running super slow on DEV environment - it is taking about 35 seconds when using Docker and 20 seconds when running with Symfony's server.

Profiler shows my controller takes too much time to compile.

[Symfony Profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL73S.png)

What I noticed is Symfony Profiler does not shows performance metrics when I run it using Docker - it does when I run using it's own server.

Any idea where I can look at? I already tried lots of workarounds without zero success.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably run Symfony in prod mode on Docker. You need to make sure to run it in the environment dev so the profiler is active. Depending on your setup you need to use web/app_dev.php instead of web/app.php or set the environment variable APP_ENV=dev in case you have a public/index.php.

Comment: I have changed my .conf to point to app_dev.php. That fixed `m/s na` after I got a few `504 Gateway Time-out` - but still taking 20 sec to load controller.php. Any other idea?